# AWS: revokeSecurityGroupIngress within a VPC

Tags: node.js, aws-security-group, aws-sdk-js

I'm using the javascript SDK to revoke a non default vpc security group's ingress based on the IP address (cidr block), but am getting an error `Source Group ID missing.` -

```
(node:8514) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingParameter: Source group ID missing.
```

I can set the same security group id to 'SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId', but this doesnt' work (and isn't really what I'm after).

Note that `actualIpPermissions` is retrieved from ec2sdk.describeSecurityGroups.SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions, not hard coded.

My code:

```
    const actualIpPermissions = [{
        FromPort:22, 
        IpProtocol:"tcp",
        IpRanges:[
          {CidrIp:"2.123.116.234/32",Description:"SSH some place"},
          {CidrIp:"203.44.22.112/32",Description:"SSH from somewhere else"}
        ],
        Ipv6Ranges:[],
        PrefixListIds:[],
        ToPort:22,
        UserIdGroupPairs:[]
      }]

    const params = {
      GroupId: 'sg-111111',
      IpPermissions: actualIpPermissions
    }

    await ec2Sdk.revokeSecurityGroupIngress(params).promise()
```

I'm using aws-sdk-js version 2.275.1

Running the equivalent command in the aws-cli works correctly:

```
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-111111 --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 22, "ToPort": 22, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "2.123.116.234/32", "Description": "SSH some place"},{"CidrIp":"203.44.22.112/32", "Description":"SSH from somewhere else"}]}]'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the `Ipv6Ranges`|`PrefixListIds`|`UserIdGroupPairs` properties being supplied to the `revokeSecurityGroupIngress` are empty arrays, the AWS SDK is still validating these.

It seems that the `Source group ID missing.` error is coming from the `UserIdGroupPairs`.

To be safe, it looks like best practice to remove any empty array / object if it isn't strictly required.

I'm not sure if this is true for all SDK functions, but it applies to the `authorizeSecurityGroupIngress` function also